# Using Netbeans 8.0.2, Java 8, Windows 7--customize library window hangs often; what to do?

Tags: java, netbeans

Here's what I see:

[image]

I was trying to add JavaDoc to the project, which uses Apache Tika.

It's hung. No buttons work. Has happened several times in past week. What is wrong/what to do?

I worry that if I use Task Manager to force close that I'll lose stuff.

[image]

But nothing about Netbeans has changed for several minutes. So I'm forcing it closed.

**EDIT**

When I try to end the task, of course I get this:

[image]

But why is this happening and what do I do?

Of course, I had no recourse but to force shutdown. Two changes not saved; no big deal, but could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will have to file a bug with Netbeans:
https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Before you do that try to find out if it is repeatable on a clean install of Netbeans and that the javadoc file itself is not corrupted or on a stalled network drive etc. Uninstall Netbeans, delete your user configuration and cache directories ( see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir ), reinstall Netbeans, add the library and immediately try to add the javadoc. If it fails again force a shutdown again. Examine the messages.log file ( see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile).  If the nothing in the log jumps out at you, submit a bug with the log attached and your simple repeatable instructions that made it happen.

Comment: It's been a long day. Thanks for the details. I'll try to follow through tomorrow.